# how do I use one live template to generate more <component > at once

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

such as I need  generate many custom vue component like

```html
<span class="search-header-tag-span">create_at</span>
<el-date-pickerenter code here
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="create_at"
>
</el-date-picker>
<span class="search-header-tag-span">create_at</span>
<el-date-picker
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="create_at"
>
</el-date-picker>
<span class="search-header-tag-span">create_at</span>
<el-date-picker
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="create_at"
>
</el-date-picker>
```

I have a live template can generate one ,But how do I use the live template to generate more   at once

Comment: What Live template is in use? Basically, you can edit a Live template content is settings: https://i.imgur.com/inKDsGX.png

Comment: i have edited a live temlate,it can generate one `<el-date-picker> ...  </el-date-picker>` vue component.if i want to generate more than one,I need redo.so I think can I  use this live template Loop to generate

Comment: I  have editer live template,it can generate one  , I want IDEA to generate several code blocks at a time instead of one.  And I didn't know I needed several such blocks until I was developing the page.  If the shortcut keys one by one are too slow for me, I want the template to generate code five times if I enter one parameter at a time like 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live templates are meant to insert common code snippets into your code quickly, and therefore by design will always be applied once. Waiting for something like a dialog box to open and entering a number will always be slower than triggering the template multiple times.

You can, however, [create](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) multiple live templates with names like `vdp`, `vdp2`, `vdp3`, etc... (`vdp` for vue date picker) using the postfix of your template  name as a parameter. Then your element will be inserted multiple times at once.
This is somewhat similar for the kotlin `fun0`, `fun1`, `fun2` live templates, where the prefix is used to indicate the number of parameters in the function.

**vdp**

```
<span class="search-header-tag-span">$PLACEHOLDER$</span>
<el-date-picker
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="$PLACEHOLDER$"
/>
```

**vdp2**

```
<span class="search-header-tag-span">$PLACEHOLDER1$</span>
<el-date-picker
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="$PLACEHOLDER1$"
/>

<span class="search-header-tag-span">$PLACEHOLDER2$</span>
<el-date-picker
    v-model="formSearch.refund_time"
    type="datetime"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    placeholder="$PLACEHOLDER2$"
/>
```

You can then enter something for each `$PLACEHOLDER` parameter and move to the next using <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

**Disclaimer.** I don't know anything about Vue though, so I can't tell if these templates actually make sense.

Comment: thank u ,it seems to be the only way

Comment: @kaitsanliew If this answers your question you [should mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so future visitors know your question is answered.